# Insert the text in textbox at x, y coordinate postion

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I am trying to drag item from a listbox and put it into the textbox. it works fine for me.
Now when i trying to drag the second item into same textbox it appends it to the last of text containing in textbox. I wanna it should be paste at the position where i drag the item into textbox. i am using following code so far

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                listBoxControl1.Items.Add("Item " + i.ToString());
         }

 private void listBoxControl1_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) {
        ListBoxControl c = sender as ListBoxControl;
        p = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        int selectedIndex = c.IndexFromPoint(p);
        if (selectedIndex == -1)
            p = Point.Empty;
    }

    private void listBoxControl1_MouseMove(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            if ((p != Point.Empty) && ((Math.Abs(e.X - p.X) > 5) || (Math.Abs(e.Y - p.Y) > 5)))
                listBoxControl1.DoDragDrop(sender, DragDropEffects.Move);            
    }


    private void textEdit1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

  private void textEdit1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TextEdit textBox1 = sender as TextEdit;
        Point newPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        newPoint = textBox1.PointToClient(newPoint);                          
        object item = listBoxControl1.Items[listBoxControl1.IndexFromPoint(p)];

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = item.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "," + item.ToString();
        }
        listBoxControl1.Items.Remove(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i use TextBox not TextEdit , try this code

```
    private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox1 = sender as TextBox;
        Point newPoint = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        newPoint = textBox1.PointToClient(newPoint);
        int index = textBox1.GetCharIndexFromPosition(newPoint);

        object item = listBox1.Items[listBox1.IndexFromPoint(p)];

        if (textBox1.Text == "")
        {
            textBox1.Text = item.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            var text = textBox1.Text;
            var lastCharPosition = textBox1.GetPositionFromCharIndex(index);
            if (lastCharPosition.X < newPoint.X)
            {
                text += item.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                text = text.Insert(index, item.ToString());
            }

            textBox1.Text = text;
        }
        listBox1.Items.Remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: It gives me some logic to solve this problem. I modified your solution a bit, as it gives wrong results in case textBox1.Text is not empty string . i.e when it goes in else part of your code.. But Thanks anyway ..